# Where I can find AWS RDS engine deprecating annoucement?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Our production RDS for mysql engine were mandatory upgrated from 8.0.20 to 8.0.28 about a weeks ago without receiving notification.

What I do:
I found this essay: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/?nc1=h_ls
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUi94.png)

It shows that there will be announcement about rds deprecating before beginning automatic upgrade.

Help wanted:
Does Anybody know the rigth place about the rds deprecating announcement? So I can know and arrange the rds engine upgrades in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. This is a site for asking questions about code problems, not cloud vendor policies. You should contact AWS Support for questions like this. They will give you a more current and reliable answer, and you are paying for the service already, so you might as well use them.

Comment: Several weeks ago I've received by e-mail an announcement about deprecating minor versions for Postgres. I hope they send the same for MySQL. Nevertheless, you can find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Concepts.VersionMgmt.html) the information about dates until they will support some MySQL versions.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is deprecation dates for mysql can be found on [this aws docs page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Concepts.VersionMgmt.html).

The long answer is that there are 2 ways this could be done.

##### AWS Console

When in RDS there is a page called "Event Subscriptions". There you can create a new subscription, sent to your email. You can have it send all maintenance events for all RDS instances. I would also recommend subscribing to OS updates under the "security patching" channel as well. Since those can cause required maintenance just the same. You can see a full list of subscribable events [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html#USER_Events.Messages.instance).

##### API

There are 2 APIs which AWS exposes for getting extra info on this topic.

> I would recommend using the tool [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) for extracting the json output from these commands

- `aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine mysql`

  - This call can be used to see the current non-deprecated versions available. You can modify this command to see only the deprecated versions like this: `aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine mysql --filters Name=status,Values=deprecated`. You could combine the output here with another call like this: `aws rds describe-db-instances` to find out if your current RDS is included in the deprecation list. This likely could be used to give you 3-6 months warning.
- `aws rds describe-pending-maintenance-actions`

  - This call can be used to see all pending maintenance for your RDS instances. This will include OS updates or minor version updates. These likely will only show up as pending the week before a required maintenance is necessary. Meaning if ran daily this would give you a 7 day warning.

## Context

#### Maintenance

> [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-maintenance-window/)

To explain AWS maintenance a bit more. AWS RDS has maintenance windows where it will upgrade the minor version by default. Downtime can be significantly reduced (typically less than 60 seconds) with multi-AZ instances. Compared to the expected 30 minutes of a regular maintenance. When using this approach the process will work as follows:

1. the standby will have maintenance.
2. Once maintenance is finished on the standby it will be promoted to primary
3. The original primary will become standby and go into maintenance

#### State

A RDS instance could go into maintenance for several reasons. This could be an OS update, or a deprecated database engine version. This will eventually happen as new versions release and current versions eventually are no longer supported.

To see the state of the pending maintenance you can visit RDS in the AWS console. There you can find a maintenance column for RDS which can have the following maintenance states:

- `required` The maintenance action will be applied to the resource and can't be deferred indefinitely.
- `available` The maintenance action is available, but won't be applied to the resource automatically. You can apply it manually.
- `next window` The maintenance action will be applied to the resource during the next maintenance window.
- `In progress` The maintenance action is in the process of being applied to the resource.

#### Deprecation

> [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#What_happens_when_an_Amazon_RDS_DB_engine_version_is_deprecated.3F)

- minor versions have 3 months before auto upgrades occur once they are deprecated
- major versions have 6 months once deprecated before maintenance occurs
- AWS supports major versions for 3 years after RDS release
- AWS supports minor versions for 1 year1 after RDS release